# Symfony 4.2: Firewall configuration doesn't load memory user provider

Tags: authentication, phpunit, firewall, configuration-files, symfony4

For my `test` environment, I have configured a memory-based user provider:

`config/packages/test/security.yaml`

```
security:
  providers:
    unit_testing:
      memory:
        users:
          test1: { password: $testpwd1, roles: ['ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN'] }
          test2: { password: $testpwd2, roles: ['ROLE_SPECIAL1_ADMIN'] }
          test3: { password: $testpwd3, roles: ['ROLE_SPECIAL2_ADMIN'] }
  firewalls:
    admin:
      form_login:
        provider: unit_testing
```

I try to test the login form in a functional test.

`tests/Controller/LoginControllerTest.php`

```php
$client = static::createClient();
$crawler = $client->request(Request::METHOD_GET, '/login');
$form = $crawler->selectButton('Login')->form(['_username' => 'test1', '_password' => '$testPwd1']);
$client->submit($form);
```

The login fails. Debugging the login process reveals that while `Kernel.php` loads the additional security configuration from `test`, the `FirewallListener` fetches a configuration which has `provider = null`.

In the standard environment, the login with producation data is successful.

What is going on?

If needed, I will provide additional code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have isolated the problem further and came to the sad realization that my problem was in fact **not** the user provider.

The configured password for the memory provider had an old encoding, and thus the newer encoding algorithm produced a hashsum that didn't match. One reason might be the migration from 3.4 to 4.2, as there were lots of changes to the configuration.

Manually encoding the target password via `php bin/console security:encode-password <arg>` solved the problem for me.